# selecting or matching specific columns by name lists[], or comma separate

Tags: python

I have a directory; inside this directory there are many sub-folders into it different extension files, so I just want to read only xlsx files, then I want to match columns by specifying the name. like using list [], or comma separate conditions . then I want to get the contents from the columns I have specified. some of the files has only one sheet and some has two sheets. the names in columns are the same for all the files. but the contents are different. so, please I need help to let the code go though files and search for only columns name that should be specified in the code, then combine them in one xlsx file output.xlsx

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
import sys
import xlsxwriter as xlsw
#import shutil

dataframes = []

path = r'C:\Users\malotaibi\Documents\mofaq', for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):,for file in files:, if file.endswith(".xlsx"):,f = (os.path.join(root, file)),print(f),dataframes.append(f),all_data = pd.DataFrame (),for f in dataframes:,dataframes = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None) ,print(dataframes),list = dataframes[['Id', 'Original id', 'Name', 'Logic/Query', 'Comments']], collection= [list],join = pd.concat(collection),join.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\malotaibi\Desktop\dd.py", line 39, in 
>       list = dataframes[['Id', 'Original id', 'Name', 'Logic/Query', 'Comments']] TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: so you are fan of one liner?

Comment: why there are many , in your one line? is it statement splitter?

Answer (score 0):

your code might be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
import sys
import xlsxwriter as xlsw
#import shutil

dataframes = []

path = r'C:\Users\malotaibi\Documents\mofaq'
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            f = (os.path.join(root, file))
            print(f)
            dataframes.append(f)
all_data = pd.DataFrame ()
for f in dataframes:
    dataframes = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    print(dataframes)
    list = dataframes[['Id', 'Original id', 'Name', 'Logic/Query', 'Comments']]
    collection= [list]
    join = pd.concat(collection)
    join.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
import sys
import xlsxwriter as xlsw
#import shutil

dataframes = []

path = r'C:\Users\jainil\Documents'
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            f = (os.path.join(root, file))
            print(f)
            dataframes.append(f)
all_data = pd.DataFrame ()
for f in dataframes:
    dataframes = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    print(dataframes)
    list = dataframes['Sheet1']
    list=list['Id', 'Original id', 'Name', 'Logic/Query', 'Comments']
    collection= [list]
    join = pd.concat(collection)
    join.to_excel("output.xlsx")
    print(join)
```

so you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook
import sys
import xlsxwriter as xlsw
#import shutil

dataframes = []

path = r'C:\Users\jainil\Documents'
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            f = (os.path.join(root, file))
            print(f)
            dataframes.append(f)
all_data = pd.DataFrame ()
join=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id', 'Original id', 'Name', 'Logic/Query', 'Comments'])
for f in dataframes:
    dataframes = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    print(dataframes)
    list = dataframes['Sheet1']
    list=list['Id', 'Original id', 'Name', 'Logic/Query', 'Comments']
    collection= [list]
    join = pd.concat(join,collection)


join.to_excel("output.xlsx")
print(join)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time, Yes, you  organized correctly

Comment: i got the result by this.

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: (Id', 'Original id', 'Name', 'Logic/Query', 'Comments')

Comment: Please, help to fix this issue. I need to match columns by name same from all xlsx files and get the contents combining to the output.

Comment: it is TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'